# Django "migrate" consuming too much CPU

Tags: django, django-migrations

Our staging server, a `t2.micro` instance on AWS was getting down constantly. On investigating, we found that when `manage.py migrate` is run CPU usage shoots up to 99%. It was easily reproducible on the local machine. We are running `Django 1.9` and `postgresql` database. I am not sure now, is it us doing something wrong or it is meant to be that way. We have around 18 apps in the project, but running `migrate app_name` also results in same behaviour. Attaching the screenshots of CPU usage.

[image: Staging server]

Also, I profiled the migrate function, here is a graph:

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you generate that graph?

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro: I used this library: https://github.com/jrfonseca/gprof2dot

Comment: I would really like to know why you are running `migrate` on a regular basis (this is how it sounds to me) instead of only after a deployment and only then if it is necessary.

Comment: @Risadinha: We have `fabfile` script for deployment of code on the server. What it does is pull the latest code from the corresponding branch-->run the migrations-->restart the server(nginx, django server). Whenever we deploy the code, server usage shoots up and the server hangs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you depending on `migrate` to run regularly? Because once the project is nearing and then entering production state, there shouldn't be many migrations to run. Or do you mean that `migrate` takes this long, even if `migrate --list` shows that there is nothing to migrate?

Also, to know what Postgres is doing, you should set up logging of queries including their time. You can filter to log only longer running queries:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-logging.html

Run those queries through the `explain analyze` sql command:

```
psql> EXPLAIN ANALYZE <complete query>;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/using-explain.html

You need to provide the information you get from `explain` to get further help.

---

EDIT:

Also, you could try to `squash migrations` if you have a lot of migration files. I could imagine that Django works itself through all of them, one by one. So if you have many apps with many files depending on each other, you can imagine what happens.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations

---

EDIT 2:

Moving this from the comment into the answer:

Does `migrate --list` also consume that much CPU? If not, then you could run it first, see whether there really is a need to migrate and only run `migrate` on those apps that have open migrations.

I think this would be the best. If you can profile in more detail, you might actually address the Django community for help. I could imagine that you have an interesting setup with which to find out how to tune the Django migrations to do less (actually unnecessary) work. But I don't know the migrations code too much so I cannot tell.
But this also depends on how many apps we are talking about, and how many migration files. If you have less than 30 apps (including 3rd party), I think it should work fine and there is something else wrong (IMHO!).

Also, you have not shown the resource usage of your server. If the slowness is due to swapping/too much RAM usage you really might be able to boost it by supplying more RAM (to the process).

Comment: Yes, I will surely try this. On a second note, CPU usage of python is going high and not of the postgresql. Could that suggest the issue related purely to Django(Python) and not database.

Comment: Yes certainly, makes also more sense. More so if it takes this long no matter how much there really is to do in the end. Does `migrate --list` also consume that much CPU? If not, then you could run it first, see whether there *really* is a need to migrate and *only* run `migrate` on those apps that have open migrations.

Comment: We tried with squashing the migrations but no luck. I guess we need a bigger box as we are facing the same issue with `compress` command also else we need to do something like @Mounir suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I believe migrations consume a lot, specially when having many models and many apps, more apps more dependencies more migrations complexity.

I would recommend starting a new instance which only run migration and shutdown after this. This way you web server could be reachable.

Comment: Ya i totally agree with @mounir, starting another instance that runs migration alone or have the postgress server running on it own instance can help.

Answer (score 0):

This does not address the problem statement exactly but a part of it. I went through the [documentation of AWS t2.micro](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html#t2-instance-limits) and found that T2.Micro instances are designed to handle the `CPU Burst` of short intervals(~1 min) happening after reasonable long intervals. From the t2.micro documentation:

> A CPU Credit provides the performance of a full CPU core for one minute. Traditional Amazon EC2 instance types provide fixed performance, while T2 instances provide a baseline level of CPU performance with the ability to burst above that baseline level. The baseline performance and ability to burst are governed by CPU credits.

Running migration's shouldn't be an issue given this ^ even if it is consuming 100% of the CPU. We investigated more and found that there were `crons` running on the server which were not supposed to be.